# jQuery CSS property names inconsistent

Tags: jquery, css

Why is the property name different for:

```
$(elem).css('padding-top')
```

and

```
$(elem).css('marginTop')
```

? Shouldn't it be:

```
$(elem).css('margin-top')
```

instead?

Comment: "For example, if you want to retrieve the rendered margin, use: $(elem).css('marginTop') and $(elem).css('marginRight'), and so on." see - http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: Sorry didn't notice. Got it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the "camelCase" or "hyphen-separated" form of properties. Both will work. See the [jQuery docs for `.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

> jQuery can equally interpret the CSS and DOM formatting of multiple-word properties. For example, jQuery understands and returns the correct value for both `.css('background-color')` and `.css('backgroundColor')`.

So to use your examples, all of the following would work:

```
$(elem).css('marginTop')
$(elem).css('margin-top')
$(elem).css('paddingTop')
$(elem).css('padding-top')
```

Comment: The statement quoted here is in the paragraph just above what the OP quotes in his comment.

Comment: @BoltClock - Haha, so it is. Perfect demonstration of how it always help to read the docs properly.

Comment: Thanks. Must have missed that part :p

Comment: sometimes simple things make terrible problem!

Answer (score 1):

There are two things. How **CSS** sees it and how you can access it using **JavaScript**. In CSS, it is:

```
#element {margin-top: ...;}
```

Whereas in JavaScript, it is:

```
document.getElementById('element').style.marginTop
```

And yes, both JavaScript way and CSS way of passing to `css()` function works.